# WPF4 DataGrid Delete Rows in RowDetailsTemplate's DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

I had a WPF4 DataGrid Control which contains another DataGrid Control in it's RowDetailsTemplate. I add a PreviewKeyDown event on both DataGrid control and monitor they're Keyboard operations.
    If press Delete key on keyboard, I'll delete the SelectedItems in DataGrid Control.
    My problem is when I want to delete a row in RowDetailsTemplate DataGrid Control. The event routed, The row in Parent DataGrid which define the RowDetailsTemplate was deleted,too. I know it's because of the RoutedEvent.RoutingStrategy settings.
    But how could I only delete the row in RowDetailsTemplate DataGrid? 
    Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an attached behavior to the nested datagrid. So that it should not bubble the deleted event anymore..

Comment: I found a temporary solution for my application. I use OriginalSource to find out the DataGridCell which delete button pressed on, and then Find the DataGridControl include the DataGridCell through WPF VisualTree. After that, I check the DataGrid.Name, if the name of the event sender name is same, it's the correct event handler I need to use. Otherwise, Let the event router to next element.